# PHP: Can I set the interpreter path in a PHP file?

Tags: php

I'm running IIS 6.0.

Is it possible to set the interpreter path (somewhat like the PHP shebang line) in a PHP File rather in the config-file?

Example:
Let's say I have two version installed (PHP4 and PHP5) the default is set to PHP4. Can I set the files individually to use another interpreter (in that case PHP5) than the default one?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think its possible by changing in php.ini file

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about IIS, but this is usually handled in Apache-land using mod_php for one one version, and fast-cgi mode for the other, and then setting the handler for php files in a .htaccess file (if you need granular control)

Answer (score 1):

How about different file extensions, like php4 and php for the current version. That should be no problem. Never did it, but that can be configured for sure, b/c your server-application then can decide which interpreter to invoke.

Comment: This might be a solution. Seems like you can do that with the "cache ISAPI extension".

Comment: I don't know, but there must be a simple and fundamental way to connect an extension with the desired server-reaction. "cache ISAPI extension" seems somewhat complex for such a setting.